# Remember if button was clicked + Stop interval doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm trying to create two buttons. One is refreshing site on interval and second one should stop it after pressing, but the stop button isn't working. Second thing is that if I press start button it's not saved in local storage as I want it. Could you guys help me with this?

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("refresh")) {
        startref()
    }
};

    function startref() {
        let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (arrayOfTabs) {
                 var code = 'window.location.reload();';
                 chrome.tabs.executeScript(arrayOfTabs[0].id, { code: code });


            });
        
        }, 1000);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh');
    }

function stop() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("startbtn").addEventListener('click', startref);

});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("stopbtn").addEventListener('click', stop);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` function takes two arguments. One is key and another is the value for the key.

change this line

```
localStorage.setItem('refresh');
```

into this

```
localStorage.setItem('refresh',intervalId);
```

When you clear the interval first get the `intervalId` stored in the localStorage and then call `clearInterval`.

```
function stop() {
    const intervalId = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Comment: Big thank you, ```function stop()``` i working fine now, now the only issue is that when I close popup window it stop refreshing site, but when I reopen popup it keeps refreshing as intended ;/